# Преимущества Telerik Open Access

Tags: .net, orm

Эта система довольно дорогая. какими уникальными характеристиками она обладает по сравнению с бесплатными аналогами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - судя по [сайту](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/individual/orm.aspx) "телериков", эта ОРМ бесплатная сегодня

2 - если покупать ее, как часть пакета, то получаешь сомнительный бонус в виде поддержки их "комьюнити"

3 - небольшие [итоги](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505789/telerik-openaccess/615673#615673), и собственно их описание:

> Benefits from using Telerik OpenAccess
>   ORM
>
> Applications can work with the
>   persisted data using object-oriented
>   development practices, including types
>   with inheritance, complex members, and
>   relationships.
>
> Applications are freed from hard-coded
>   data access layers and dependencies on
>   a particular data store (database) or
>   storage schema.
>
> Mappings between the data model and
>   the storage-specific schema can change
>   with minimal changes to user
>   application code.
>
> Developers can work with data
>   persistence object model that can be
>   mapped to various data stores
>   (different database management
>   systems).
>
> The data persistence object model can
>   be mapped directly to the data store
>   (forward mapping), or can be extracted
>   from the data source (reverse
>   mapping).
>
> Multiple data persistence models can
>   be mapped to a single storage schema.
>   Also single domain model could be
>   mapped to multiple data
>   stores/schemes.
>
> Language-integrated query (LINQ)
>   support provides compile-time syntax
>   validation for queries against a data
>   persistence model. All persistence
>   classes are still normal CLR objects,
>   and as such can be easily tested by
>   state of the art unit tests.
>
> Advanced caching features are
>   available out of the box, providing
>   optimizations like: Connection Pool
>   settings, Compiled Query Cache /
>   Prepared Statement Cache, First Level
>   Cache, Distributed Second Level Cache.
>
> Multi-tier application scenarios are
>   supported through the ObjectContainer
>   API.
>
> No reflection is used for data
>   persistence and changes tracking. The
>   product can be used even in Medium
>   Trust environments.
>
> All the needed
>   persistence code is post-build
>   generated through byte code
>   enhancement.